# setuid confusion, change owner of files created to particular user:group

Tags: setuid

I am trying to setup a directory /opt/www in such a way that when a user who belongs to the group django creates/modifies files and directorys within, they are set to owner django and group django.

I have looked at [setuid and setgid confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55093/setuid-and-setgid-confusion) and [Special File Permissions (setuid, setgid and Sticky Bit)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4078/secfiles-69/index.html)

From this I **chmod 6775 /opt/www** However **touch /opt/www/test** yeilds

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 wurst  django    0 Mar 16 13:58 test`

Q) How do I implement this requirement of having any user that belongs to group django, and creates a file or folder within /opt/www, to have it automaticaly chown **django:django**? (not **:django**)

Secondly, I am curious if this is nessisary for security purposes or if simply doing a chown -R :django and not worying about the owner beingt he user who created the file.

> Note: in addition to creating the group django and adding my regular user account to this group, I have also created a system user via **useradd -rg django django**

Im oposed to storing my project within my home directory, although this will be on a live site, the site itself wont see much traffic as It will not be submiting it to search engines not premoted.  Its sole purpose in life it as a learning platform for myself.

What might I be doing wrong? Do  i need to write a custom script and schedule a cron job for it?

Comment: Related question: [How do you get linux to honor setuid directories?](https://serverfault.com/questions/371541/how-do-you-get-linux-to-honor-setuid-directories). TL;DR: Linux ignores setuid on directories, so you'll need to use alternative means if it's important (test to find out!)

Comment: I very much appreciate this link, not sure how or why I missed it but its definitely helpful.  Beyond the debate one user suggested access control lists, to set default permissions.  I am investigating this as my solution.  Thank you.